# How to ignore special characters in named email format using regex in vbscript

Tags: regex, vbscript

I a have a vbscript that checks a named email format if correct using regular expression. However, upon named email strings with special character, my regular expression does not match below named email:

```
"Davé Lory, Sr." <jhonson@test.com>
```

I'm using the regular expression to check valid named email:

```
^\s*(([\"][\sa-zA-Z0-9_\-\.\'\,\&]*[\"])|([\sa-zA-Z0-9_\-\.\'\,\&]*))*\s*[\(<]\s*([A-Za-z0-9_\x27]+((\.|-)['A-Za-z0-9_\x27]+)*\@[A-Za-z0-9]+((\.|-)[A-Za-z0-9]+)*\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)\s*[\)>]\s*$
```

But it can't match if the named email contain special a character like é or È etc..

How can I ignore this special characters in regular expression?

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not ignore them, you need to match them.

You can try this one here

```
^\s*((\"[^"]*?\")|([\sa-zA-Z0-9_\-\.\'\,\&]*))*\s*[\(<]\s*([A-Za-z0-9_\x27]+((\.|-)['A-Za-z0-9_\x27]+)*\@[A-Za-z0-9]+((\.|-)[A-Za-z0-9]+)*\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)\s*[\)>]\s*$
```

I removed your `[\"][\sa-zA-Z0-9_\-\.\'\,\&]*[\"]` with

```
\"[^"]*?\"
```

1. you don't need square brackets around a single character
2. `[^"]*?` is a lazy match that will match anything that is not a `"` till the next `"`

You can see it online here at [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/SHsuBygraR)

I have not checked the rest of the expression, what I have seen on rubular is that there are many capturing groups. If you don't need the result then you can make them non capturing by `?:` after the opening bracket (e.g. `(?:\"[^"]*?\")`).